# How to handle commands from databound controls in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

This question seems so simple yet I cannot find an answer. I am sure I am missing something.

I want to use a databound control (say a ListView) with a control that does a postback (a Button) inside the item template. I want the button to perform some action on the data in this item.

The code looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebFormListCommand.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="TestWebApplication.WebFormListCommand" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ListView ID="lvTest" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" 
            onitemdatabound="lvTest_ItemDataBound" onitemcommand="lvTest_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestWebApplication
{
    public partial class WebFormListCommand : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                lvTest.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 5);
                lvTest.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                lvTest.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(5, 5);
                lvTest.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void lvTest_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnTest");
            int value = (int)e.Item.DataItem;
            button.CommandName = "someCommand";
            button.CommandArgument = value.ToString();
            button.Text = value.ToString();
        }


        protected void lvTest_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            //e.CommandArgument has the new value from the new databinding
        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that when the button is pressed e.CommandArgument has the value from the postback databind. If I do not do a databind on postback the event is not raised at all. In most cases this is not a problem because you databind to the same data. However if one user deletes for example item 3 and the second user decides to delete item 3 in the same time the second user will actually delete the fourth item because the items will be reordered on postback. This can be avoided if ViewState is enabled but it should be possible to execute a command without ViewState (after all the one place ViewState should be avoided is databound controls). To add insult to injury I can clearly see that the original (correct) value is posted to the server. It can be retrieved via Request.Form["lvTest$ctrl2$btnTest"] (the key is the UniqueID of the actual control that triggered the postback)

I have tried many ways to apply the command to the correct item like using button click instead of item command, using DataKeys, etc. but I couldn't get the right value for the data item back. It seems like the databound control always uses the row number to get the command argument instead of the values that were actually posted by the browser. The only way I found was to manually look in the Request.Form collection but this does not seem right. Of course I can work around the problem by hooking up a JavaScript function and an AJAX call but I want to know how this issue can be resolved in a pure WebForms way. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Move code from Page_Init into Page_Load
2. Comment out

   lvTest.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(5, 5);

   lvTest.DataBind();

And see if it works.

I'd also set `CommandName` declaratively and bind `ComanndArgument` property rather than setting it on `lvTest_ItemDataBound`

UPDATE:

1. Don't rebind on postback
2. Enable viewstate on your `ListView`

Markup:

```
<div>
    <asp:ListView ID="lvTest" runat="server"
        onitemdatabound="lvTest_ItemDataBound" onitemcommand="lvTest_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
<asp:Label Text="" ID="lblMessage" runat="server" />
```

C#

```
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            lvTest.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 5);
            lvTest.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            //lvTest.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(5, 5);
            //lvTest.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void lvTest_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnTest");
        int value = (int)e.Item.DataItem;
        button.CommandName = "someCommand";
        button.CommandArgument = value.ToString();
        button.Text = value.ToString();
    }


    protected void lvTest_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //e.CommandArgument has the new value from the new databinding
        lblMessage.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: If I comment out the databinding on postback and disable ViewState the click event is not raised at all. I am databinding in the code behind because prior to ASP.NET 4.5 there is no way to use statically typed declarative databinding i.e. declarative databinding via Eval/Bind is evil. However declarative databinding does not make any difference in this case.

Comment: It works because your ListView control does not have its ViewState disabled. As stated in the question everything works fine if you enable ViewState but somehow I don't feel like enableing ViewState for ListViews and Grids because this is exactly the place where it should be disabled to prevent growing the page size.

Comment: @Stilgar sorry, didn't see that part; I think you're a victim of premature optimization syndrome.

Comment: Turning off ViewState for Grids and ListViews bound to heavy objects is not premature optimization. It is pretty meaningful optimization. Currently I do not have this problem I would solve it with AJAX or by digging in the Request.Form values but it is VERY strange that there is no way to write normal delete from a list without ViewState.